# i have a issue in java code in netbeans graphics mode

Tags: java, button

I tried to create buttons in java that draw something with this code.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import  java.awt.event.*;

public class primeraapplet extends Applet implements ActionListener{

    Button bt1, bt2, bt3;
    int type=-1;

    @Override
    public void init() {
    setLayout(null);
    bt1= new Button("Linia");
    bt2=new Button("Rectangle");
    bt2=new Button("Rodona");

    bt1.addActionListener(this);
    bt2.addActionListener(this);
    bt3.addActionListener(this);

    bt1.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 50);
    bt2.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 50);
    bt3.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 50);

    bt1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    bt1.setBackground(Color.black);

    bt1.setFont(new Font("times New Roman", Font.BOLD,16));
    bt2.setForeground(Color.red);
    bt2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    bt2.setFont(new Font("times New Roman", Font.BOLD,16));

    bt3.setForeground(Color.black);
    bt3.setBackground(Color.white);
    bt3.setFont(new Font("times New Roman", Font.BOLD,16));

    add(bt1);
    add(bt2);
    add(bt3);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Button ref;
        ref = (Button) e.getSource();
        if (ref==bt1)
            type=1;
        else if (ref==bt2)
            type=2;
        else
            type=3;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (type==1)
            g.drawLine(100, 65, 90, 150);
        else if (type==2)
           g.drawRect(100, 65, 90, 190);
        else if(type==2)
            g.drawOval(100, 65, 90, 90);
    }
}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at primeraapplet.init(primeraapplet.java:34)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It'd be great to point out what line the error actually occurs on, especially since I removed a bunch of unhelpful comments.

Comment: In your `paint()` method, why do you have two `else-if` statements with the exact same condition? Also, that if-statement would need braces or it wouldn't work. Ditto in `actionPerformed()`. Also with `paint()` you have `type` used but never declared. There's lots going on here.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. The API was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void init() {
    setLayout(null);
    bt1= new Button("Linia");
    bt2=new Button("Rectangle");
    bt3=new Button("Rodona");  //You had bt2=new Button("Rodona");
```

Variable error in code. You cant set same nam with new Button alongside with same variable!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting your layout to null?

```
setLayout(null);  // shouldn't this line be the source of your problems?
```